# Vue.js + git build process

Tags: vue.js

I use vue.js + vue-cli + webpack to build my applications. During development I will run `npm run dev` to have webpack continuously watch my sources, compile everything, and reload the browser. To create production build, I can simply run `npm run build`. I would like to do this in a way that when I make a git commit, if my sources have changed, the build is created automatically.

My current approach is to simply use git pre and post commit hooks to automatically run `npm run build` and add the built files to the commit. This has the following downsides:

- Even if other parts of the repo are changed, I re-run the build process for the Vue app, and it takes a very long time.
- It makes resolving merge conflicts nearly impossible.
- It creates a lot of cruft in the repo, ballooning its size

Typically I use a Vue.js frontend with a Django backend in the same repo, and deploy to Heroku or similar via a `git push`. What other methods are out there for accomplishing this task that don't have the above downsides?

Answer (score 1):

Write a script in the package.json scripts section with something like

`build && git commit -m "Build commit"`

Comment: There are two issues with this solution. First, I would now have to run a completely separate thing to make commits, and more importantly I'd have to teach everyone on my team to use this non-standard command. Second, it doesn't address things like rebases and merges.